# chef client 404

Tags: chef-infra

While running

```
$chef-client -S https://ip-172-31-87-170.ec2.internal -K /etc/chef/4thcoffee-validator.pem
The server returned a HTTP 404. This usually indicates that your chef_server_url is incorrect.
```

I am getting the above output

my client.rb is

```
log_level :info
log__location STDOUT
chef_server_url "https://ip-172-31-87-170.ec2.internal"
trusted_certs_dir "/root/.chef/trusted_certs"
```

Comment: So, are you sure you have the right URL?

Comment: Yeah the URL is right

Answer (score 0):

The server URL generally should look like `"https://ip-172-31-87-170.ec2.internal/organizations/$something"` unless you are running a very old version of Chef Server.